# How to store shopping cart items ? Cookies?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Just learning and building with VUEJS.  I want to build a shoppingcart for our site so user can add multiple items in cart.

How do i store the items in the cart ?

- User Add item 1 to cart
- User browse site
- User Add item 2 to cart
- User leaves the site
- User come back next day
- User see that item 1 and 2 is still in basket

How does this work in VUEJS ?  With cookies ?

best,
remco

Comment: i would say for not registered user to use localstorage and for registerd user to store the shoppingcart in a database

Answer (score 1):

We can use VUEX for storing data in our vue application, to persist the data we can use [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) plugin. This plugin will use the browser's local storage for the purpose.